# Parse a stringstream into strings and doubles

Tags: c++, string, parsing, input, stringstream

I am writing a program that takes inputs on one line as follows:

Run 10.1 50.2

Where "Run" is a string and the rest of the line are doubles. Scientific notation and negative numbers can also be used as double inputs:  -5.88e-11 for example (Standard C++ library allows this).

Here is the initial code I tried.

```
string command; 
double input1; 
double input2; 
getline(cin,input);
stringstream ss(input);

ss >> command >> input1 >> input2;
```

The problem with this approach is that if a blank space or a letter is input in the place of a double the output of the stringstream will be 0. I believe this is because there are no null holders for double in C++.

Another approach I tried is to read each input as a string, check that the string is numerical and convert it to a double. However, this becomes complicated when scientific notation and negatives can be entered. Attempt at this:

```
for (int i=0; input1[i]; i++){
    if (isdigit(input1[i])){\
        isDigit = true;
    }else{
        isDigit = false;
    }
}
```

How can I parse this input with a string and alphanumerical doubles on the same line? (while retaining negatives and scientific notation)

Thanks!

Comment: What is an example of input that you are having trouble with?

Comment: What do you want the code to to if it's given "Run abc 50.2"?

Comment: If the input is: Run abc 50.2  input1 (a double) from the stringstream will be a 0. This is probably because abc is not a valid double. I am looking for a way to check that a double from the stringstream is actually a double.

Comment: Another example input is Run  50.2 in which input1 is replaced by a space. The same outcome will occur and input1 (double) will be set to 0.

Comment: Why not do `cin >> command >> input1 >> input2;`? Could save you some trouble.

Comment: cin doesn't solve the problem as any input that is not strictly a double (ex: abc, a blank space) will be read as a 0. I still need to preserve 0s as inputs. I thought that through stringstream there might be a way to parse it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::cin` directly and checking if there's any error in parsing the stream.

```
std::string command;
double arg1, arg2;

if (std::cin >> command >> arg1 >> arg2) {
    std::cout << command << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg2 << std::endl;
} else {
    // error!
}
```